# Failed orders are placed using new order status rather than Canceled

Tags: orders, order-status, magento-2.2.1, authorize.net

I'm in the final stages of setting up my Magento 2 Store and I am trying to add authorize.net as a payment option. I am getting an error:

```
Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the seller.
```

Which when I check the transact.dll from the request I see:

```
An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant. 
An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. The 
following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card. 

  The credit card number is invalid.
```

This all makes sense as I am using an invalid credit card number, the issue is that in the Magento admin the order has been placed with a status of processing.

This order failed but has been placed in the system as if it succeeded, which is causing orders to look as though the customer has paid. From my research I have discovered that when this happens the order should be set to the cancelled status, not the New Order Status so I'm not quite sure what is happening here.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo I figured it out, I was missing the new[Cancelled] status in **Store > Order Statuses** so when authorize.net tried to set the status to cancelled it could not and rather defaulted to what it had. Easy fix, just assigned the 'cancelled' status to the 'new' state and all was well.

Hope this helps someone else if they end up with a similar issue.